# MLM php generate ul li

Tags: php

I am a newbie to php and i am currently doing mlm project.The logic is below.
I have table with following fields childname,parentname,position(left or right).
I want to convert to it as a tree and if any parent has already left child then the coming left child as a child of last left child and same logic for right child insertion.
I have a jquery plugin to convert ul li to tree.
pls help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add more context. show some code. right now, the Q is barely understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/ making tree view design using HTML and JQuery. You can also bind with PHP.

Hope it will helps you!!